# loop and zip dictionary and list into a new dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

How can I double loop over a list and dictionary

provided with this dict:

```
tabs = {
        'RESULT' : 'result_out',
        'INFO'   : 'info_out',
        'LOGGING'    : 'loggging_out',
        }
```

And this list:

```
li = [11,22,33]
```

I would like to map the dictionary to the list to get this result:

```
tabs = {
        'RESULT' : [11,'result_out'],
        'INFO'   : [22,'info_out'],
        'LOGGING'    : [33,'loggging_out'],
        }
```

since:

```
list(zip(list(tabs.keys()),list(tabs.values()),icons))
```

is equal to:

```
[('d', 'a', 1), ('e', 'b', 2), ('f', 'c', 3)]
```

I thought this would make it:

```
{key:[icons[i],value] for key,value,i in zip(list(tabs.keys()),list(tabs.values()),icons)}
```

but this gives:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Do you know how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> tabs = {
...         'RESULT' : 'result_out',
...         'INFO'   : 'info_out',
...         'LOGGING'    : 'loggging_out',
...         }
>>> li = [11,22,33]
>>>
>>> {a : [c, b] for (a, b), c in zip(tabs.items(), li)}
{'RESULT': [11, 'result_out'], 'INFO': [22, 'info_out'], 'LOGGING': [33, 'loggging_out']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this?

```
count = 0
for i in tabs:
    tabs[i] = [li[count],tabs[i]]
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
{'RESULT': [11, 'result_out'], 'INFO': [22, 'info_out'], 'LOGGING': [33, 'loggging_out']}
```